# How to write a ruby method that returns a count of items that are alike in two arrays but in different positions

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to code a version of the game Mastermind in Ruby. To do this I need to write a method that will return a count of how many elements two different arrays have in common but are at different positions. I already have a method that can return the count of items that are correct at the same index.

For instance:

```
comparing ["red", "green", "red", "orange"] to ["blue", "red", "blue", "blue"]
#should return 1

comparing ["red", "red", "orange", "orange"] to ["orange", "orange", "red", "red"]
#should return 4

comparing ["green", "green", "orange", "blue"] to ["green", "green", "orange", "red"]
#should return 0
```

Comment: It is an interesting exercise. Are you sure you don't want to solve it yourself?

Comment: @DigitalRoss: I know the feeling :)

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see the minimal code you've written that demonstrates the problem you're having. SO isn't a code writing service and currently it looks like you want us to write it for you. Asking us how to write it is a very broad question, but fixing the problem that is keeping your code from working is most likely a very specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f a, b
  c = [a, b].transpose.inject [] do |m, e|
    m << e if e.first != e.last
    m
  end.transpose
  puts c.first.size - (c.last - c.first).size
end

f [:red, :green, :red, :orange],    [:blue, :red, :blue, :blue]     # => 1
f [:red, :red, :orange, :orange],   [:orange, :orange, :red, :red]  # => 4
f [:green, :green, :orange, :blue], [:green, :green, :orange, :red] # => 0

# it works with Strings, also

f %w/red green red orange/,    %w/blue red blue blue/     # => 1
f %w/red red orange orange/,   %w/orange orange red red/  # => 4
f %w/green green orange blue/, %w/green green orange red/ # => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I went another way than @DigitalRoss.

```
def match_at_wrong_position(master, guess)
  guess = guess.dup                          # dup, so we do not modify the input param
  master.each_with_index.inject(0) do |count, (item, index)|
    found_at = guess.index(item)             # is it provided as a guess
    next count if found_at.nil?              # not found
    guess[found_at] = nil                    # make sure it is not found again
    found_at != index ? count + 1 : count    # if not same position, then increment
  end
end

p match_at_wrong_position(["red", "green", "red", "orange"], ["blue", "red", "blue", "blue"])
p match_at_wrong_position(["red", "red", "orange", "orange"], ["orange", "orange", "red", "red"])
p match_at_wrong_position(["green", "green", "orange", "blue"], ["green", "green", "orange", "red"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invent a a method to count the correct colors (never mind the positions), then subtract the count of colors that are correct at the same index (which you already have).